# Can I 'clear' memory when copying/manipulating fits files with python?

Tags: python, memory, shutil

I am working with ~300 x 200MB fits files and trying to write a code that copies them into new directories based on their filename.  Below is a sample of my code. I have written my filenames into lists (blocks) in blockarray.  I then loop over each block and use shutil to copy the fits file.

My computer keeps slowing down then freezing when I run my code.  I've had a look around and found gc.collect(), but that doesn't seem to help.  Is there anyway to clear the memory after each file is copied?

```
for block in blockarray:
    for i in range(1,len(block)):
        old_path = current_path + num + '/' + block[i]
        new_path = current_path + num + '_ex/' + block[0] + '/' + block[i]
        if not os.path.exists(new_path):
            shutil.copyfile(old_path, new_path)
            print "%s copied" %(block[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would help, but you could give it a try: [vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/).

Here is an example from its documentation:

> We have 3 big datasets, a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt but only 2 of them
>   will fit in memory at once. If we have a.txt and b.txt in memory but
>   would now like to work with b.txt and c.txt, we could just start
>   loading up c.txt but then our system would evict pages from both a.txt
>   (which we want) and b.txt (which we don't want).
>
> So let's give the system a hint and evict a.txt from memory, making
>   room for c.txt:
>
> ```
> $ vmtouch -ve a.txt Evicting a.txt
>
>        Files: 1
>  Directories: 0    Evicted Pages: 42116 (164M)
>      Elapsed: 0.076824 seconds
> ```

P.S. Instagram [recomended this tool](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances), that's how I know it, but I haven't played with it myself.